# How do I make a shortcut using arrow key with PySide2?

Tags: python, pyside2, qshortcut

I want to add a keyboard shortcut to a button with Qt5 + Python (Pyside2). Code for making a shortcut with a regular key:

```
import sys
import random
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.hello = ["Hallo Welt", "你好，世界", "Hei maailma",\
            "Hola Mundo", "Привет мир"]

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Click me!")
        self.text = QtWidgets.QLabel("Hello World")
        self.text.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.text.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Titillium", 30))
        self.button.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Titillium", 20))

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.text)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        shortcut = QtWidgets.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence('o'), self.button)
        shortcut.activated.connect(self.magic)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.magic)


    def magic(self):
        self.text.setText(random.choice(self.hello))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    widget = MyWidget()
    widget.resize(800, 600)
    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If I replace that `shortcut = ...` line with this:

```
shortcut = QtWidgets.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence(QtCore.Qt.LeftArrow), self.button)
```

Nothing happens. What am I missing?

I also tried converting the QtCore.Qt.LeftArrow value to string (nothing happens), and tried making the QShortcut directly with the Qt.LeftArrow (complains about nullptr). Using QtCore.Qt.Key_Left as parameter for QShortcut gave me nullptr too.

Answer (score 2):

I found out:

```
shortcut = QtWidgets.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence.MoveToPreviousChar, self.button)
```

The list of actions are here: 
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequence.html#StandardKey-enum

Answer (score 2):

With PySide2 something like the following should works:

```
QtWidgets.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence("right"), self.button, self.magic)
```

which will directly connect the button with callback function.